# Haproxy Backend module uses IP instead of domain name

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to use domain name in haproxy backend module configuration

```
backend prod_auth
  balance leastconn
  option httpchk GET /auth-service/generalhealthcheck
  http-check expect string "Service is up and reachable"
  server auth-service-1 domain-service.com:8080 check
```

but haproxy uses IP(10.1.122.83) of domain-service.com instead of the domain name itself to do health check, it becomes an issue because my service works on domain name not on IP.

```
root@ram:~$ curl http://domain-service.com/auth-service/generalhealthcheck
["Service is up and reachable"]

root@ram:~$ curl http://10.1.122.83/auth-service/generalhealthcheck
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

I cannot make my service working on IP as there are multiple other services running in the same server and uses different domain name(rDNS).

I don't know why haproxy is using IP instead of domain name, i verified it using WireShark. is there any way I can force haproxy to use domain name mentioned in backend modules?

I tried setting in /etc/hosts but that does not work

```
domain-service.com domain-service.com
```

I am using HA-Proxy version 1.7.8 2017/07/07

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `Host` header send to your domain using the same `option httpchk` as following:

```
backend domain-service-backend
   mode http
   option httpchk GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ domain-service.com
```